# force Microsoft Edge to use engine EdgeHTML

Tags: microsoft-edge

How can I (using any settings) force Edge to render page with engine EdgeHTML instead of Blink?

I have Edge Version 99.0.1150.39 which uses Blink (from Chromium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve this. Support for Microsoft Edge Legacy has ended on March 9, 2021 and Edge based on chromium doesn't have EdgeHTML engine.

Edge based on chromium has two engines: Chromium engine and Trident MSHTML engine. You can enable [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) to make sites render in IE in Edge browser if you need.